# how to use file return by 1 method into another method of the same class

Tags: java, file-io, io

**Step1:** user clicks on a button file gets downloaded.

**Step2:** contents of that pdf is read.

**Expected :** before downloading delete the file if it already exists

**tried :**

```
    public File A() {
        String userDir = System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Downloads";
        File file = new File(userDir+"\\PDFStatement.pdf");
        return file;
    }

    public void clickxxxButton() {
        try {
            File f=pst.A();
            if (f.exists()) // to delete the already existing file before downloading
            {
                f.delete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        clickOn(xxxxButton);// here pdf file gets downloaded
    }


    public void verifyPDFContents() {
        try {

            //Loading an existing document

            File file =pst.A();// here pst is the object of the same class where this method resides

            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
              //Instantiate PDFTextStripper class
              PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

              //Retrieving text from PDF document
              String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
              System.out.println(text);

              //Closing the document
              document.close();
              file.delete() 
        }
         catch (IOException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am getting error for pageobject dependency injection. While if i have everything (except the delete )inside verifypdfcontent(like declaring and creating the file),it works fine

Comment: `before downloading delete the file if it already exists` - where; at the server or at the client machine?

Comment: on local machine where test is downloading the file